# django 1.6 - how do I insert a class-bassed view into a template as an {% include %}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My current template structure has a `home.html` that extends from a `base.html`.  That `home.html` file also has its own `{% include %}` tags that pull in from other templates (contact forms, etc).

The problem I am having is that when I use the `{% include %}` tag on a class based view, nothing gets rendered in my template.  I can still go to the url of the class based view and it renders just fine there.

In this case `frontpabe/contact.html` is a typical function based view, while `frontpage/skills_list.html` is a class based view.

home.html:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4">

      {% block contact %}
      {% include 'frontpage/contact.html' %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block skills %}
      {% include 'frontpage/skills_list.html' %}
      {% endblock %}

    </div>
```

contact.html:

```
{% block contact %}

    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="I want a free estimate...">
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address (optional)">
        <p></p>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="here are some things I need..."></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

skills_list.html:

```
{% block skills %} 

    {% for item in skills_list %}

        <h3 style='background-color:yellow;'> {{ item.skills }} </h3>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem won't have anything to do with whether it's a function-based view or a class-based view--the `{% include %}` tag merely includes the **template** itself--it doesn't call the view. It's literally as if you just copied + pasted the text of the contact or skills templates into your front page template.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't be 100% sure, but a likely place for your problem is that the view class or function for your homepage doesn't have a variable skills_list  or, if it does, that it is empty. So your `skills_list.html` template *is* being used, it's just rendering the results of looping over an empty list (a quick check would be to add a tiny bit of static text, like "HELLO?" to `skills_list.html` outside of your `{% for ... %}`; if you see that, you're definitely rendering the template.

If it is a missing `skills_list` variable, it's almost certainly because of the misunderstanding about views/templates. You're probably defining that template in the CBV associates with `skills_list.html` template--but, again, the `{% include %}` tag doesn't call your view; it just includes the raw template itself.

Comment: your are completely correct.  it turns out the error loop doesn't work in my `contact.html` include either.  now my problem is that i don't know how to embed both the template and the view into the `home.html` template.

Comment: In the view that produces your homepage, you can use the same code that you use in your SkillList view, and add a skills_list variable to the context of the homepage.

If you're using a class-based-view for your homepage, you can do that in an overridden get_context_data() method. If you're using a function view for your homepage, you can just put the code in the base of your function and add 'skills_list' to the returned context.

The actual line to get the skills is up to your models but it'll be something like `skills_set = Skills.objects.all()` or `skills_set = Skills.objects.filter(...)`.

Comment: Got it - it turns out I was misusing the templates concept entirely.  Thank you for suggesting that I add a variable to my `homepage` view, that clears up the root problem of my question.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck out there!

Answer (score 0):

Extends and include are different and should not be used together.  If you are going to define blocks then have the children template extend the parent and override the blocks- no includes necessary:

**home.html**:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

  {% block contact %}
  {% endblock %}

  {% block skills %}
  {% endblock %}

</div>
```

---

**contact.html**:

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% block contact %}

    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="I want a free estimate...">
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address (optional)">
        <p></p>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="here are some things I need..."></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

---

**skills_list.html**:

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% block skills %} 

    {% for item in skills_list %}

        <h3 style='background-color:yellow;'> {{ item.skills }} </h3>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

---

### Alternatively, you could use includes:

**home.html**:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

  {% include 'frontpage/contact.html' %}
  {% include 'frontpage/skills_list.html' %}

</div>
```

---

**contact.html**:

```
    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="I want a free estimate...">
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address (optional)">
        <p></p>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="here are some things I need..."></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

---

**skills_list.html**:

```
    {% for item in skills_list %}

        <h3 style='background-color:yellow;'> {{ item.skills }} </h3>

    {% endfor %}
```